# How to close wood support beams?

Tags: drywall

The drywall is installed in the basement on the wood support beams. What are my options to close those gaps between drywall and concrete wall of the window opening? I plan then to paint everything.
[image]

Comment: You've provided some nice close up detail pics, but it's a bit hard to tell what we're looking at from that close. Can you get a single shot showing an overview of the area. Maybe draw arrows on it to show where each of the detail pics came from? All in all, though, I think you just need to cut thin strips of drywall to cover the wood and corner bead, or maybe just apply thin layers of drywall mud to bring it out to the wall surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for something called "filler rod". It's actually a soft, flexible foam that comes coiled up like rope (usually in short lengths like 2-3 meters). You can get it in greater lengths if you search.

This stuff is also available in different diameters. You want something that is just a little too big for each gap. You **do not** want to jam 5/8" rod into a 1/8" gap. At best it won't work, at worst you'll break something important.

Once you install the filler rod, you can use that as the backing for a bead of caulk. (So put the filler rod in all the way, but not too far in, because you'll have to fill whatever gap you leave with caulk!)

```
_   _     <- "surface" of window/door frame
 |~|      <- filled with caulk
 |O|      <- filler rod
 | |      <- empty gap full of air
```

Once you have the caulk in place, just wait for it to set up/cure, and then paint over it if you want to.